# PHP foreach and continue

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I've come across a function in some code I'm trying to debug and I'm not sure why it is written like this

```
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    if (!isset($company->account)) {
        continue;
    }
    some_function($company, $sectorsMap, $subSectorsMap);
}
```

Is this the same?

```
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    if (!isset($company->account)) {
        some_function($company, $sectorsMap, $subSectorsMap);
    }
}
```

How does the continue control structure work?

Cheers

Comment: any (good) php developer could do that 10 different ways.

Comment: @ElliotB. The two snippets are not the same. In the 1st, `some_function` only executed when `$company->account` is set, and the other way in the second snippet.

Comment: i think the second code should be if(isset($company->account)) instead of if(!isset($company->account))

Comment: @tuananh so continue breaks out of the foreach loop when the company is not set?

Comment: @DanielHarper no it just skip the current element and go to the next one in the for loop

Comment: @tuananh thanks I've got it now

Comment: second option should probably remove the `!` for them to be equivalent...

Comment: The answer to this question would be entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made the `if` statements equivalent, I'd say the top version is more generic and better for more complex statements due to the following:

1. If you had multiple `if - continue` statements, the first approach would allow you to list them in order without nested indentation which could keep your code cleaner. Using the second approach, you could get a lot of nested indentation.
2. If you had a lot of code after the `if - continue` statement(s), the first approach would have the bulk of the code indented less and possibly easier to read.

In your specific example with one statement out side of the `continue`, it may not much difference, but if you were going to pick one approach to use everywhere, the first approach might be nicer for complex loops.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just needed clarification on how continue worked I now realise the difference. Cheers